# How does adding two axis get calculated?

Tags: python, numpy

Update: Apologies. I have updated the code to match the output now.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,4,1)
matrix = x[:6,np.newaxis] + x[np.newaxis,:]
```

That produces this table that looks like this in rows and columns:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

which is this array:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5],[3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

My question is how does numpy add up each cell to produce this result?

Comment: this is known as broadcasting. look into https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny sorry about that. I updated the code to match the output.

Comment: Beyond knowing the resulting dimensions are (4,1) and (1,4), and the `broadcasting` rules, what do you need to know?  The action takes place in a complicated set of compiled functions, but it's safe to imagine the 2 arrays being replicated to (4,4) shape, and then added element by element.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment your code doesn't give that result. The matrix I get using your code is this:

```
[[0, 2],
 [2, 4]]
```

To understand the way this result is calculated lets split up the process:

```
#--- 1
x = np.arange(0,4,2)
```

The first line gets an array of numbers between 0 and 4 with a step of 2 (not including the 4). The output of this line is the following array:

```
[0, 2]
```

Next the two parts of the equation:

```
#--- 2
part1 = x[:4,np.newaxis]
part2 = x[np.newaxis,:]
```

The first part takes the first 4 elements of array x and expands it in axis index 1 (so now the elements of our original array are in the axis index 0 (rows)). The output of this part is the following:

```
[[0],
 [2]]
```

The second part takes the array x and expands the dimensions in the axis index 0 (the elements of the original array are now axis index 1 (columns)). The output of this part is:

```
[[0, 2]]
```

Finally adding the two parts:

```
matrix = part1 + part2
```

The result of this is the following matrix:

```
[[0, 2],
 [2, 4]]
```

At each index combination for example [0, 1] the result is the element of part1 at index [0] plus the array of the element of part2 at index [1], thus the result is 0 + 2 = 2.
Similarly:

```
matrix[0, 0] = part1[0] + part2[0] = 0 + 0 = 0
matrix[0, 1] = part1[0] + part2[1] = 0 + 2 = 2
matrix[1, 0] = part1[1] + part2[0] = 2 + 0 = 2
matrix[1, 1] = part1[1] + part2[1] = 2 + 2 = 4
```

Edit: Yes the updated code gives the result you mention. Anyway, the same logic applies.

Comment: Yes thank you! This explains it. I also used this same logic to follow through with the updated code and yes it adds up. Thanks again!